# Keyboard stopped working for one user - and one user only

Tags: gnome, keyboard, ubuntu-gnome

Since yesterday, my keyboard stopped working. I type but nothing appears in the text input. If, for example, I press "Enter" on the browser's address bar, no request will be made. The mouse works perfectly, but both my notebook's keyboard and the USB keyboard I use fail to work.

It only happens with my default user account: if I log into another account on my machine (Ubuntu 14.04 with Unity) it will work; it also works at ttys. However, if I lock my default account, the keyboard does not work at Light DM either.

**Notice:** it can happen on other versions of Ubuntu, either with Gnome or Unity or the default interface. Verified (!) with 20.04.

Comment: This has helped me a lot! Still possible to have this problem with 20.04 --- and given that there is no visual indication of the thing, it drove me crazy. I will add a bounty and suggest to remove the specificity to 14.04...

Comment: @Rmano I would recommend leaving 14.04 tag, because it gives the idea that solution works on all releases between 14.04 and 20.04.

Comment: @user.dz yes, you're right

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1716666) solved the mystery: I just enabled the "Slow keys" option by mistake. It is easy to solve:

- To to the cog icon at the top right corner, choose "Settings":
  [image]
- Go to "Universal Access":
  [image]
- Go to the "Typing" tab.
- "Slow keys" is marked as on:
  [image]
  Toggle it to "off".